# Breaking a big class into smaller methods

Tags: c#, .net, methods, refactoring, system.net.sockets

I have difficulty breaking a class consisting of one method into smaller methods. I have a simple socket class that Initiate, send and receive a message in one step (one method). Now I would like to divide this into separate steps of Initialization, Send, Receive, and End as below. I have tried so many different combinations but I could not get it working.

My program that works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SocketCom
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class SyncSocketClient
        {
            public static void StartClient() \\<<-----------
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                IPHostEntry ipHost  = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
                IPAddress ip = ipHost.AddressList[1];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 11111);
                Socket sender = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
                int byteSent = sender.Send(msg);
                int byteReceived = sender.Receive(msg);
                Console.WriteLine($"[ECHO TEST] {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byteReceived)}");
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();     
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyncSocketClient.StartClient();
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to below (not working).  I do not care about the access modifier or being static or not. I just want to break one method into three separate methods in any possible way.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SocketCom
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class SyncSocketClient
        {
            public static void StartClient()\\<<-----------
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                IPHostEntry ipHost  = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
                IPAddress ip = ipHost.AddressList[1];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 11111);
                Socket sender = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);
            }   
            public static void Send(string message)\\<<-----------
            {   
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                int byteSent = sender.Send(msg);
            }   
                
            public static void Receive()\\<<-----------
            {       
                int byteReceived = sender.Receive(msg);
                Console.WriteLine($"[ECHO TEST] {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byteReceived)}");
            }
            
            public static void EndClient()\\<<-----------
            {
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();     
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyncSocketClient.StartClient();
            SyncSocketClient.StartClient("Hello");
            SyncSocketClient.Receive();
            SyncSocketClient.EndClient();
        }

    }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The `[.net-framework-version]` tag's [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-version) states: _"For questions specifically on how to deal with .Net versions. For other questions on .Net, please use a .net + version tag."_ - is this what your question is about?

Comment: What is "not working" beyond `SyncSocketClient.StartClient("Hello");` should be `SyncSocketClient.Send("Hello");`?  Also, you can't use a variable local to one method (`sender` and `msg`) in other methods.

Comment: My platform is .net framework 4.8

Comment: @Lance U. Matthews, I get so many errors to list. I definitely do not know how to correctly pass and share variables between methods.

Comment: _"My platform is .net framework 4.8"_ Then you can add the [tag:.net-4.8] tag

Comment: You should not edit the solution into the question; instead, [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Also, the reason for all the errors in your attempt at multiple methods is because of the `\\<<-----------` after each method name; comments in C# (`//`, `/* */`) use forward slashes, not backslashes.  Fixing that turns the list of compiler errors from noise into simple steps that are clear and easy to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things I can see you're misunderstanding based on your attempt to do this. One is the attempt to access variables in locations where they are not [in scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/). `sender` and `msg` are two examples. Another is that you're not returning `msg` from the `Send` method so it can be used in the `Receive` method. I would suggest this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.php) to help you understand the basics of methods in C# **before proceeding**.

If you're using Visual Studio, [Visual Studio Automatic Refactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2022) will help with this, however I'd strongly encourage you to understand what the tool has done to your code once you've used it and not proceed until you do understand it, this is a fundamental programming concept.

Select the code you want to extract to a method, right-click, and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings...", then "Extract Method". The IDE will create the method and all the necessary parameters for you.

Answer (score -1):

The First step is to keep the Socket variable out of methods. So declare at class level and use this socket in all methods.
static Socket sender;

Comment: @ Pankaj Thank you for the tip. I had tried << static Socket sender>> before and moved that into class level but still there were so many problem with other parts that I could not solve. Could you please explain more steps?